# Does a subcover need to be a proper subcover?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

**Definition:** A Space $\mathbb{X}$ is said to be **Compact** if every ***Open Cover*** has a ***Finite Subcover***.

**My Question:**
Suppose, Space $\mathbb{X}$ has an Open Cover $A$ whose finite subcover is $A_{1}$.
 Now, $A_{1}$ becomes a open cover of space $\mathbb{X}$. Suppose that $A_{1}$  has a finite subcover $A_{2}$. Again, Repeat the process.
After fintely many steps of this process, we will arrive at a stage when, there will be no finite subcover for the previously made cover. 
(Say, the process ends at Nth step. So, there is no finite subcover at (N+1)th step. )
 So, By Definition, I conclude that: *There is No space $\mathbb{X}$ which is compact.*

Comment: Well the cover $A_1$ is itself a finite cover, so $A_2$ could be taken equal to $A_1$.

Comment: It is not forbidden for subcovers to coincide with the original cover.

Comment: @drhab Can You please elaborate, why it is not forbidden for subcovers to coincide with the original cover.?

Comment: It is just the same principle as used for sets. If $A$ is a set then it has subsets and $A$ itself (so coinciding with the original set) is one of those subsets. So also subsets of a set are not forbidden to coincide with the original  set.

Comment: @drhab So, it means that if I am able to construct a finite subcover for an infinite cover. Then, in principle,I have  shown that the space $\mathbb{X}$ is Compact.

Comment: It means that the reasoning in your question is not sound. You are saying that "after finitely many steps of this process we will arrive at a stage s.t. there is no finite subcover at next step". Every finite cover has a finite subcover: itself.

Comment: And indeed: if you have can show that for an infinite open cover always a finite subcover exists then you have shown that $X$ is compact.

Comment: @drhab In the back of my mind, I had the notion that the subcover needs to be a proper subcover. The reason, for this is that I have only encountered examples in which, the author and instructors, construct an infinite cover and then, a finite subcover. So, I assumed that the containment is always proper.

Comment: I have edited the title; it's confusing if the title is a direct statement that everyone knows is false.   Even with the question about subcovers, it is clear that every textbook believes there *are* compact spaces, so the question is really about clarifying the definition, not about contradicting every text.

Comment: @Kumar: you are welcome to enter your own answer, which could mostly consist of your most recent comment.

Comment: The reason that  authors and instructors have used only examples where the original cover is infinite (and so a finite subcover is necessarily proper) is that the other possibility, where the original cover is finite, was considered too trivial to mention, since the original cover will itself serve as the desired finite subcover.

Answer (score 2):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

A cover $\mathfrak{C}$ of $X$ is a family $(C_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$ of subsets $C_\alpha \subset X$ such that $\bigcup_{\alpha \in A} C_\alpha = X$. A subcover $\mathfrak{C}'$ of $\mathfrak{C}$ is *any* subfamily $(C_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A'}$ with $A' \subset A$ such that $\bigcup_{\alpha \in A'} C_\alpha = X$. In particular, $A' = A$ is allowed. This is equivalent to $\mathfrak{C}'= \mathfrak{C}$.